# Use 1 storyboard on any button

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have created this storyboard:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Btn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="#FF323232"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="Btn">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

How can I use this storyboard on more than 1 button not just "Btn"? What would I need to write in Storyboard.TargetName to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, you would be best off creating or editing the buttons template, and add the storyboard to that.  Then other buttons would reference that template and "inherit" the storyboard and all styling and functionality from the template.

In the example below, there are two buttons, each of which reference ButtonStyle1.  Button Style 1 has a trigger which says to begin the MouseOver storyboard.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnSizeChanged1"/>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1" AutoReverse="True">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" ThemeColor="Metallic" Height="48.277" Margin="0,0,-37,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="193.093,39,251.093,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,39,85.093,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="115.907"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could it be possible to create a style for all buttons where I define the storyboard and then create a additional style for any button which would inherit the storyboard?

Comment: You could potentially do that, but the element in the style you are particularly concerned with will be the template.  I have to get to a meeting, and I can't check on it at the moment, but I don't think you can have a template based on another template (similar to how you can have a style based on a style...)  I will have to get back to that later...

Comment: Nope.  cant base templates on other templates it seems.  Why, if I may ask, do you want to have two otherwise identical templates where one uses this storyboard, and the other does not?

Comment: I would like to create two buttons, which would have different appearance but have the same animations when you mouse over them.

Comment: Well, you can store a storyboard as a resource and reference it from the triggers from each of the templates.  That I think may be the best it will get for now, unless anyone else has some more input.